# Gedit Online Language Specs Generator

Tags: syntax-highlighting, gedit, language-specifications

Is there a online generator, or something like that, of new highlightings for gedit?

I am using a not known language and I would like to have syntax highlight, but it seems like too complicated and I though that could exist some online creator.

Comment: I had to write a syntax spec a while ago for a language called Frege. I just did it by hand! :P We really need an online generator for this! Perhaps you could make it, good sir? :)

Comment: Good ideia, we could work together, what do you think about it?

Comment: Sure. I could try to help. Open a repo on Github or something and I could see how I can contribute. I'm not a huge web developer, but I could probably manage. :)

Comment: Could we talk via e-mail, gtalk, fb, or something?

Comment: I've set up a [Stack Overflow chat for this question](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28911/online-gedit-syntax-highlighting-generator). I've already added you on it too. We should be able to discuss there. :)

Comment: I just can't enter it. Please, contact me by mail: richard.lopes92@live.com

Answer (score 1):

- GtkSourceSchemer (see github source here : https://github.com/jonocodes/GtkSourceSchemer) could help you to do that. This is a theme maker for applications using themes based on Gtksourceview (gedit included)

or

- Scribes Theme Generator (http://scribes.sourceforge.net/themegenerator.php) is an online generator

Answer (score 0):

No online generator I know of, but you can find a similar language that has a spec already and start from there. There is a pretty good pool to choose from under

/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/